# Brand new build powercycling, no display

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power

My boyfriend and I have a new rig here with all new parts:

MoBo Gigabyte GA-X99-UD3,
CPU Intel Core i7-4960X 3600 MHz Ivy Bridge-E,
two 8GB of DDR4 RAM,
GTX 960 4G video card,
650w Rosewill power supply,
WD Blue terabyte harddrive model# 10EZSEX.

We've troubleshooted, tested connections, triple checked with manuals, unplugged ram, unplugged everything but the motherboard and CPU, reapplied the thermal silver (pea sized amount spread carefully with a credit card), and it will not boot. It won't even beep. It does power on- fans spin, things light up, but no BIOS loads. If everything is attached, the computer will have power for 10-12 seconds; if it's just the CPU/power source there are 17 seconds before the new power cycle

when the computer shuts off, all lights turn off (even the green on lights on the inside on the power source). It stays off for 3 seconds before going through the motions again.

Monitor has yet to see signal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is the CPU power connector plugged in? This is a 8 pin connector right next to your CPU. Having it unplugged tends to cause this to happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, original poster here (now with login- hopefully this won't get deleted if I specify I am the user510535).

Anyway I double checked everything and yes that is connected. I tried the power source in our other rig and that worked. At this point I'm just waiting to hear from the mobo people, thanks for the help but it looks like its a faulty piece of equipment

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts